# Avoid pushing duplicate objects to an angular array

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have multiple checkboxes in my angular application. When user checked and unchecked checkboxes I want to pass those true/false values into an array. It's happening from below code.
But my problem is as you can see the below console.log, it has duplicate checkbox values(index 0 and 3 have same thing) and push it to the array.

I want to know how to check duplicate objects and avoid pushing object to the array.

**.ts file**

```
layerChange(e:any){
    var isChecked = e.target.checked;
    var id = e.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
    const layer = {
      isChecked: isChecked,
      id: id,
    }
    this.layers.push(layer);
    console.log(this.layers);
  }
```

**.html file**

```
 <input id="population" (change)="layerChange($event)" type="checkbox">
 <input id="gender" (change)="layerChange($event)" type="checkbox">
 <input id="householdIncome" (change)="layerChange($event)" type="checkbox">
```

console.log(this.layers)

```
**0: {isChecked: true, id: 'population'}**
1: {isChecked: true, id: 'age'}
2: {isChecked: false, id: 'population'}
**3: {isChecked: true, id: 'population'}**
```

Comment: Well you would want to remove the item(s) from the array if they are unchecked, no? If you do that, it solves your current issue :)

Comment: Hi @AT82, Thanks for the comment. But actually no. Scenario is like this. First, user will checked population, age checkboxes. Then user will unchecked the population checkbox. Then again when he checked the population tab, Then in my array population true value is duplicated. I want to avoid happening like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an entry exists first using either :

```
 var id = e.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
 var attr = this.layer.find(x => x.id === id);
    if(!attr)
      this.layers.push(layer);
```

or

```
this.layer.filter(x => x.id === id)
```

**Edit**

in your scenario is better to construct the array only one time in page load.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.layer = [{id: 'age', isChecked: false}, {id:'population',isChecked: false}]
  }
```

and then alter the check state when user check/uncheck :-

```
layerChange(e:any){
    var isChecked = e.target.checked;
    var id = e.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
    this.layer.find(x => x.id === id).isChecked = isChecked;
    console.log(this.layers);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please look for this scenario. Firstly, user will checked population & age checkboxes. Then user will unchecked the population checkbox. Then again when he checked the population tab, Then in my array, population true value is duplicated. I want to avoid happening like that.

Comment: @KalanaTebel see my edit

Comment: @AbdusalamBenHaj, why not use `[(ngModel)]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string array which contains only ids and you can insert or remove elements from the array as per the selection

```
 layerChange(e:any) {
         const id = e.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
         const index = this.layers.findIndex(el => el === id)
         if(index === -1) {
          this.layers.push(id);
         } else {
         this.layers.splice(index, 1)
         }
        
         console.log(this.layers);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

my GOD!

Kalana (and others) we need re-thinking the problem using "variables". Yes, Angular philosophy is binding variables. Variables in .ts makes the values are showed in the .html

So, some simple like declare an array of object in the .ts

```
layers:any[]=[{isChecked: true, id: 'population'},
              {isChecked: true, id: 'age'},
              {isChecked: false, id: 'population'}
             ]
```

Allow us write in .html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let layer in layers">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="layer.isChecked" 
         (change)="onChange()">
</ng-container>
```

In .ts we has a function:

```
onChange(){
  console.log(this.layers) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Finally , I was able to find a solution. Thank you.**

```js
layerChange(e:any){
  var isChecked = e.target.checked;
  var id = e.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
  const index = this.layers.findIndex(el => el.id === id);

  const layer = {
    isChecked: isChecked,
    id: id,
  }
  
  if(index > -1){
    this.layers[index].isChecked = isChecked;
  }else{
    this.layers.push(layer);
  }
  console.log(this.layers);
}
```